# Invalid "main" entry for ts-node when running ts-node-dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've started a typescript project using yarn, I ran the following commands:

```
yarn init -y
yarn add typescript -D
yarn tsc --init
yarn add ts-node-dev -D
```

and then I created a script called dev that runs `tsnd src/index.ts`, and it gives the following error

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ tsnd src/index.ts
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:329
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Documentos\Rafael\Rafael\Softwares\Typescript\base-typescript-project\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:321:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:682:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Documentos\Rafael\Rafael\Softwares\Typescript\base-typescript-project\node_modules\ts-node-dev\lib\compiler.js:26:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'D:\\Documentos\\Rafael\\Rafael\\Softwares\\Typescript\\base-typescript-project\\node_modules\\ts-node\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'ts-node'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS D:\Documentos\Rafael\Rafael\Softwares\Typescript\base-typescript-project>
```

It seems like yarn isn't installing ts-node right, because whenever i run `npm i ts-node -D` and then i run `yarn dev` it works, does anybody have a clue?

Here's my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "base-typescript-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsnd src/index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.61",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there was something wrong with my yarn, so I ran `yarn clean cache` and created a new project and now it works.

Comment: yarn cache clean   cmd is